# Use private IP connect Cloud Google Setting

Tags: mysql

My location IP is private IP like 10.0.216.49.
How to setting Mysql Connection on Cloud Google ?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What error did you get?

Comment: Normally,I will add one ip in public ip setting.But now my workplace wirless has change 172.xx..xx..x to which i mention in my question.how should I do to allow 10.xx.xxx.xx to access mysql on cloud google?

Comment: In Google document is show "You can not specify a private network (for example, 10.x.x.x) as an authorized network.",But my IP is private network in my workplace.It mean I can't do anythink?